# Coordinate transformation of basis vectors

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, covariance

**The question**
Let $e_a$ be the coordinate basis vectors in a manifold described by coordinate system $x^a$. The vector displacement between two nearby points is given by 
\begin{equation}
ds=dx^ae_a=dx'^ae'_a
\end{equation}
where a prime denotes the same quantity measured in a different reference frame.

Using the relationship $dx^a=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^b}dx'^b$, it is easy to see that 
\begin{equation}
e'_a=\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x'^a}e_b
\end{equation}
However, my textbook (General Relativity An Introduction for Physicists by Hobson Lasenby and Efsthathiou, pg 60-61) says that the following must obviously be true as well:
\begin{equation}
e'^a=\frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^b}e^b
\end{equation}
My question is how do I prove this?

**Attempt at a solution**

I can see that this would follow if we assume that $dx_a$ transforms as \begin{equation}
dx'_a=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^b}dx_b
\end{equation}
And the proof goes as:
\begin{eqnarray}
dx_ae^a&=&dx'_ae'^a\\
&=&\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^b}dx_b e'^a
\end{eqnarray}
Switching the dummy index to b on the left side we get:
\begin{equation}
dx_be^b=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^b}dx_b e'^a
\end{equation}
which gives:
\begin{equation}
e^b=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^b} e'^a
\end{equation}
Interchanging primed and unprimed variables as well as a and b we get
\begin{equation}
e'^a=\frac{\partial x'^b}{\partial x^a} e^b
\end{equation}

This proof seems a bit clumsy to me, AND I am unable to prove my starting equation (my text uses the transformation rule for $e'^a$ to prove it later). Is there a better way of deriving this result WITHOUT using the equation I started with?

Comment: Which text? Which page?

Comment: The text is General Relativity An Introduction for Physicists by Hobson, Efsthathiou and Lasenby, page 60-61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by the "coordinate basis vectors" with their upstairs  indices.  The basis vectors of the tangent space ${\rm TM}_p$ at a point $p$ are usually written with downstairs indices as 
$$
{\bf e}_\mu= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}. 
$$
The basis vectors with upstairs indices are 
$$
{\bf e}^{*\mu}=  dx^\mu
$$ 
and they are the basis vectors of the dual space $({\rm TM}_p)^*$.

If we insert a displacement vector
$$
\delta {\bf x}= \delta x^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}
$$
into the dual basis element $dx^\nu$ we use the definition of the dual basis 
$$
dx^\nu(\partial_\mu)= \delta^\nu_\mu
$$
  to  get
$$
dx^\nu( \delta {\bf x})= \delta x^\nu
$$
Thus $dx^\nu$ is a machine into which we drop a vector a get back the numerical components of the vector.

If we change coordinates to $x'^\mu$ we have
$$
{\bf e}'^{*\nu}= dx'^\mu= \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\nu} dx^\nu=  \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}{\bf e}^{*\nu}
$$ 
and
$$
{\bf e}'_\mu= \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^\mu}= \frac{\partial x^\nu }{\partial x'^\mu }\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}= \frac{\partial x^\nu }{\partial x'^\mu }{\bf e}_\nu
$$

Comment: This is really helpful. In the book I am following, the $e_{\mu}$ are defined as $\partial s/\partial x^{\mu}$ where $\delta s$ is the infinitesimal vector separation between two nearby points. Thinking of them as operators  $\partial /\partial x^{\mu}$instead makes this a lot easier. Thanks so much!

Comment: @samgon This is the usual approach by mathematicians. It is due to Elie Cartan. It looks a bit weird at first, but after a while one gets used to it and computationa advantages are substantial.